# window unload not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onunload

I have to call post service on browser close and notify user data. I got it working on Chrome and Internet Explorer but on Firefox 30 it is never called. The following is the code snippet, please let me know if any other solutions..

```
window.onunload = function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:9200/doLogout",
  type: "POST",
  data: {type: 3},
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // ...
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: `window.onunload` works well in FF, but browser doesn't wait your asynchronous task to be done, it just closes the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can beforeunload be used to send XmlHttpRequests reliably](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479103/can-beforeunload-be-used-to-send-xmlhttprequests-reliably)

Comment: @nmaier I donot want it to run on before unload, i know it works in before unload, i want it to run after user confirm leaving the page

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you send from `unload` or `beforeunload`. The question I duped yours to answers if you can reliably send stuff at all when unloading (no).

Comment: @nmaier before unload is calling every single time but not unload

Comment: That's more or less coincidence and nothing to rely upon.